# An equality about the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

From the Plancherel identity, we know that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\widehat{f}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi$$
is valid for all $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions and in particular for Schwartz functions $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Also we know that the Fourier transform of the derivative $f'$ of $f$ is $2\pi i\xi\widehat{f}(\xi)$. From this we see that 
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f'(x)|^2\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}} (2\pi \xi)^2|\widehat{f}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi. \tag{*}
\end{equation}
for all $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Now I want to show that $(*)$ is valid for all $f\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$. The hint says that we can use a limiting argument and use the fact that $L^2$ is complete. I know that $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$, but I don't know how to use the limiting argument.

Comment: the Fourier transform is an unitary operator $L^2 \to L^2$. $f(x)$ is in $W^{1,2}$ hence $f'(x)$ is in $L^2$ and $(2 \pi \xi) \hat{f}(\xi)$ is in $L^2$ and $\|(2 \pi \xi) \hat{f}(\xi)\| = \|f'(x)\|$. the fact that $L^2$ is complete is used in the proof that the Fourier transform is an unitary operator from $L^2$ to itself, because it is an unitary operator on a dense subset of $L^2$ (the Schwartz functions)

Comment: @user1952009 Why $f'$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ implies that $2\pi\xi \widehat{f}(\xi)$ lies in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? $\widehat{f'}=2\pi i\xi \widehat{f}$ is  valid for $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, is it still true for $f\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: you don't understand what you want to prove. once you proved that the Fourier transform is an unitary operator $L^2\to L^2$, by definition  of "unitary" you get $\|f\|_{L^2} = \|FT[f]\|_{L^2}$ for every $f \in L^2$. hence, what you'd like to prove is that $\|h\| = \|FT[h]\|$ for every $h \in S$ implies $\|f\| = \|FT[f]\|$ for every $f \in L^2$, i.e. that the FT is an unitary operator $L^2 \to L^2$. and what I wrote above is that for proving that you have to use the fact that $S$ is dense in $L^2$

Comment: @user1952009 No, The fact that the Fourier transform is unitary is not enough to prove the claim, you must prove that $\widehat{f'}=2\pi i\xi \widehat{f}$ for all $f\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$ first. Since the derivative is weak derivative not the classical derivative, this is not trivial.

Comment: what means unitary then ? and by the way, how do you define the Fourier transform if $f \not \in L^1$ (i.e. if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{- 2 i \pi \xi x} dx$ possibly doesn't always converges) ? this is why we define at first the FT for $g \in S$, then the general FT on $L^2$ as $FT[f](\xi) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} FT[f_\epsilon](\xi)$ where $f_\epsilon(x) = f(x) e^{-\epsilon^2 x^2}$ or $f(x) e^{-\epsilon^2 x^2} \ast u_\epsilon$ where $u_\epsilon$ is the appropriate mollifier

Comment: @user1952009  The Fourier transform can be defined on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ using continuous liner extension (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension), thus it suffices to define the Fourier transform on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ which is a dense subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: ok, then you already know nearly everything . hence, delete your question and ask it better, defining everything precisely : what we already know and what we'd like to prove. (or simply look at any course on the Fourier transform on $L^2$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36607/discussion-between-xiang-yu-and-user1952009).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a sequence of Schwartz functions $(f_n)_n$ which converges in $W^{1,2}$ to $f$. This implies $f_n ' \to f'$ in $L^2$ and hence $(2\pi i \xi) F[f_n] = F[f_n '] \to F[f']$ in $L^2$.

But we also know $F[f_n] \to F[f]$ in $L^2$. Now, use that convergence in $L^2$ yields a subsequence which converges almost everywhere.

From this, it is not hard to see that $F[f'] = (2 \pi i \xi) F[f]$. Now use that $\int |f'|^2 = \int | F[f']|^2$ to conclude the proof.

The same argument as given here is very often useful.

Comment: Note to OP: If $ A (f)=B (f) $ for each $ f $ in a dense subset and $ A $ and $ B $ are continuous with respect to the Sam norm for which we have density then $ A=B $. This is the general density argument that you always hear about.And it is trivial to check in this generality

Comment: @Bananach: True, but I don't see how we can easily apply this here, since we do not know a priori that the RHS of the desired identity is continuous with respect to convergence in $W^{1,2}$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, didn't think long enough before writing

Comment: Thanks, in the last line of the first paragraph, it should be $F[f']$ not $F[[f]$.

Comment: @XiangYu: Thanks, fixed.